# Aplicar CSS condicionando quando duas classes estiverem juntas

Tags: css

Tenho duas situações:

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="title">Título</span>
    <span class="time">12:00</span>
</div>
```

e

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="title">Título</span>
</div>
```

Quando existir o "time" preciso aplicar um estilo tanto à class "time" quando à class "title". E quando não existir o "time" preciso que "title" tenha outro estilo.

Comment: Se vc estiver construindo o HTML via backend (ex., PHP + banco de dados), fica mais fácil de resolver. Se não, creio que só conseguirá isso via JS.

Comment: @Sam tio, nada que colocando uma `order` na casa não resolva :D

Comment: @hugocsl Não sei pq mas me lembrei agora daquele carro véio do Maniero :D

Comment: @hugocsl Espero que a pergunta seja apenas uma curiosidade, pq me recuso a imaginar que alguém irá fazer isso em produção rs... Muito mais simples criar 2 classes: uma quando tiver o `time` e outra sem o `time`.

Comment: @Sam haha como só tinha a tag CSS acho que não teria outra opção além dessa... Se vc sabe o que está fazendo é uma solução até bem consistente, mas vai dele  saber como isso vai escalar...

Comment: É pq as classes já vem do fullcalendar. Como não posso mexer no core deles eu fiz uma solução à parte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da para fazer com uma técnica de CSS usando `order`.

Com isso vc pode aplicar uma regra de CSS usando o seletor `+`

Com o order vc vai mostrar visualmente na tela, o `Title` antes do `Time`, mas no `DOM` o `Time` vai vir antes do `Title`, assim vc aplica o CSS com `time+title { seu css }`

Para usar order o *container* pai tem que ser `flex` ou `grid`, e assim vc coloca `order: -1;` no `title` para ele sempre ser o primeiro elemento na tela (não no DOM).

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor, **repare que no código o `Time` está antes do `Title`, mas na visualização na tela o `Title` está antes do `Time`**

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  color: red;
  order: -1; /* com isso o title sempre vai vir antes do time na TELA, não no DOM */
}
.time + .title { /* condição que aplica cor diferente no title, caso haja o Time no DOM */
  color: blue; 
}

.time {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span class="time">12:00 </span> 
  <span class="title"> Título </span><br>
  <i> quanto tem time o title fica blue</i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="content">
  <span class="title"> Título </span><br>
  <i> quando não tem time o title fica red</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu!

Comment: @FernandoIssler legal que bom que ajudou ai!